# Squeezing and stretching of an image on certain coordinates only using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-manipulation, stretching

I need to stretch and squeeze an image on certain proportion as in the following image is it possible to do this using asp.net C# or is there any Image tools for this.

[image: First one is the original image and second and third are the output images]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution for this using the imagemagick library, it can be downloaded from [here](http://magick.codeplex.com/).

Once the reference to the Magick.net dll has been added you can use the following code to distort the image,

```
double[] Points =  new double[] {
                0,0,                0,0,
                0,500,              50,500,
                0,1000,             0,1000,
                420,0,              420,0,
                420,500,            370,500,
                420,1000,           420,1000
            };
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage("E:/ImageManipulation/WebApplication2/images/Test.jpg");
            image.Distort(DistortMethod.Shepards,Points);
            image.Write("E:/ImageManipulation/WebApplication2/images/Result.jpg");
```

See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) for some more examples of the Shepards method